# How would this query be done in Eloquent?

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I am learning to use the laravel eloquent and I have this query

```
SELECT SUM(precio_total) FROM `venta` GROUP BY (MONTH(fecha));
```

So far i wear this

```
$cantidad_venta = Venta::select('SUM(PRECIO_TOTAL) as suma_precio')
                                ->groupBy('MONTH(fecha)')
                                ->get();
```

I try to go through axios, but it throws me an error

```
return response()->json($cantidad_venta);
```

I would really appreciate an answer, thank you very much

Comment: What is the error? You'll likely need some `DB::raw()` wrappers around those expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Do this in multiple ways. check the following code below :

```
  $ventas = Venta::select(DB::raw('SUM(PRECIO_TOTAL) as suma_precio'))
                 ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(fecha)')
                  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cantidad_venta = Venta::select(DB::raw('SUM(PRECIO_TOTAL) as suma_precio'), DB::raw('MONTH(fecha) as month'))
                            ->groupBy('month')
                            ->get();
```